# Selective transparency?

Tags: transparency, masking

[image: A sample scene]

I'm trying to create a scene in which an object is transparent with respect to some objects and not others. The screenshot above shows kind of the effect I'm dealing with. I have here a cube with one face (on the right side) removed, in front of a backdrop and with a sphere inside it. I want the cube to be transparent enough to show the backdrop and anything else in the scene that I put behind it; at the same time, the sphere inside the cube needs to be completely invisible, except when seen through the open face.

Effectively I want the cube to behave in a way similar to an invisibility cloak effect, but the cube itself needs to be visible, yet transparent. I keep thinking I've found a way to make this work, only to run into problems. I'm out of ideas now but not yet willing to give up on the scene. Ideas?